# Why method with argument List<Object> can not accept a list of any type like List<A> as argument in java?

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance

Suppose we have a method `void m0(List<Object> lst)`, why can't we call it with an integer list `List<Integer> iLst = new ArrayList(); m0(iLst);` while with method `void m0(Object a)`, `m0(1);` is OK. Logically a list of Integer is a list of object, why `m0(iLst);` is not correct?

Comment: Suppose `m0` starts with: `lst.add("this isn't an integer");` - don't you think that might confuse code that expects `iLst` to only contain integers?

Comment: Generics. Hard. You might want to study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this thing called variance.

Let's use some types we are all familiar with:

`java.lang.Integer extends java.lang.Number extends java.lang.Object` *

### Covariance

In a covariant system, you can write:

`Number x = new Integer();`

but you cannot write:

`Integer y = new Number();`

As you might surmise, basic assignment and such in java is all covariant.

Makes sense, right? Whatever I can do to a reference to a `Number` instance, I can do to an `Integer` instance, such as invoking `.intValue()` on it. But in reverse it does not hold; `Integer` may have methods that `Number` doesn't.

Therefore, as you're familiar with, basic java assignment, parameter passing etc is **covariant**.

### Contravariance

In a contravariant system, you **cannot write**:

`Number x = new Integer();`

but on the flipside, this actually works:

`Integer y = new Number();`

### Invariance

This is the inflexible one; in this one, neither works. The only thing you can do is:

`Integer y = new Integer();`

### Okay, so, what about generics?

Whereas java is covariant for basic stuff, generics isn't. Generics is contravariant, or covariant, or invariant, depending on how you write the generics.

- Covariant: `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // legal`
- Contravariant: `List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); // legal`
- Invariant: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // only integer will do here`

With `void m0(List<Object> list)`, you've picked invariant. For the generics part, only `<Object>` will do (and for the `List` part, that is covariant as 'normal' java is, so an `ArrayList<Object>` can be passed here, but e.g. a `List<String>` cannot).

### Um, wtf? Why???

Because... life. That is how real life works.

Imagine it did not. I can do this, then, and break everything:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // MARK THIS LINE!
numbers.add(new Double(5.0));
Integer x = ints.get(0); // ERROR!
```

In the above, if it had compiled and run, the last line would be an error, as the .get(0) call would retrieve a double value which isn't an integer. Fortunately, the above does not compile; the error occurs on the marked line. That's.. because the compiler should disallow this. Generics by its very nature **are invariant**.

Now, covariance can exist. For example, if you have a method that will sum up the result of invoking `.intValue()` on each of the Numbers inside, then you could write:

```
public int sumAll(List<Number> list) {
   int result = 0;
   for (Number n : list) result += n.intValue();
   return result;
}
```

but that's a bad way to write it; you've decreed that the parameter is invariant, thus, you cannot pass a `List<Integer>` to this thing. But the code is covariant. It would work just as well if you pass a list of integers. So, you should write that as `public int sumAll(List<? extends Number> numbers)` instead.

Here is an example of invariance:

```
public void addSumToEnd(List<Number> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Number n : list) sum += n.intValue();
    list.add(sum);
}
```

Because we're adding a number here, you couldn't write `List<? extends Number>`. After all, we're adding an `int` and you can't do that to a `List<Double>`. The only acceptable lists you can feed in here are `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` and there's no way to express that in java.

For lists, it's easy: "contravariance = adds" (`.add()`, `.addAll()`, etc), "covariance = reads", "invariance = does both". For other generified types it may not be that simple.

Presumably if your `m0` method class will only ever 'read', then you can make it covariant, and write:

```
public m0(List<?> lst) {...}
```

and `<?>` is just short for `<? extends Object>`. You've denied yourself the ability to call `.add`, but you can still call `.get`, and crucially you can pass `List<String>` to such a method, whereas you cannot if it read `List<Object>` (but, on the other hand, you can call `.add()` on a `List<Object>` parameter, and add whatever you like!

*) These are real types in java, but Number is abstract. For the purposes of this example, assume it is not, and that they all have no-args constructors. The point is the type relation, not anything particular about these types.